# How can I resolve the "Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: 'RNGoogleMobileAdsBannerView' was not found in the UIManager" error?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I got this error while integrating "React Native Google Mobile Ads".

I follow the installation and setup steps but cannot find the solution.

I'm using Expo,

```
"dependencies": {
    ...,
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^11.0.0",
    ...
}
```

I have followed the official documentation but have not been able to resolve the error https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads.

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Even after setting up the development client, I was still encountering the same problem. Then I tested the app on a physical device, and it was working properly. You need to integrate the ads well in your app, generate the APK, and check it again. Otherwise, there is no other solution. If you find one, please do share it.

Comment: I download the APK and when I try to open it. It keeps stopping!!

Comment: You should follow the documentation. First, practice the code mentioned in the documentation and generate apk of your app. Hopefully, then your app won't stop. Once you have practiced it, things will be easier for you.

Comment: I follow the documentation. But I have one question. Is it necessary to use a real App ID from AdMob? Currently, I'm using a dummy ID the same as mentioned in the documentation.